# How does rubber toughening work?

Tags: polymers, materials, plastics

I’m doing a research project which involves rubber toughening - the particular example I'm looking at is the toughening of SAN polymer (styrene-acrylonitrile) with polybutadiene to make ABS. What I'm looking for is a description of why the process makes the material tougher, whereas everything I can find online seems to be research about the effects of different factors on the toughness. If anyone could provide a source that would be great.

Comment: I think you need to be much more specific about what kind of "rubber."

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE! At this point I recommend taking the short [tour] of the site. As stated in another comment, you will need to be more specific about what you are really looking for in order to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_toughening) answers your question quite directly:

> "This important property [rubber toughening] is entirely due to the
>   small rubbery domains that aid in arresting crack propagation, thereby
>   increasing toughness/energy needed to break the material."

The same article gives an example using the materials sited in your post:

> "Well-known rubber toughened polymers include high impact polystyrene
>   (HIPS), rubber-toughened nylon, and acrylonitrile butadiene styrene
>   (ABS). In HIPS, polybutadiene domains are dispersed in a polystyrene
>   matrix; in rubber-toughened nylon, typically cis-polyisoprene is
>   dispersed in a Nylon matrix; in ABS, polybutadiene domains are again
>   used, but for both polystyrene and acrylonitrile."